# How to break on instruction that hasn't been traced yet?

Tags: ida, debugging

I have some questions regarding IDA and Ollydbg.

First, is there a way to create a record with traced instructions and let the debugger automatically break, when it hits an instruction that hasn't been traced in the record ?

My second question is refering to IDA tracing options. 
I wrote a simple Win32 GUI application in C++ which mainly consists of a message pump (`GetMessage`, `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`) and a `WindowProcedure`. I tried the following:

1. I set a breakpoint in the message pump;
2. Started the tracing from there;
3. Set a second breakpoint in the `WindowProcedure` that triggers a break when I click on a button.

What IDA traced are only the instructions from the message pump not the ones from the `WindowProcedure`, though it should at least have traced the `DefaultWindowProc` instruction.

Can anyone tell me whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Intel's Pin software can do this. It may take some effort, however.
2. Is WindowProcedure a system call? I don't think IDA can debug kernel code - you may have to use windbg if that is the case.

Comment: IDA can connect to the remote WinDbg instance.

Answer (score 1):

STEGANOGRAPHED IMAGE :) COPY HEXEDIT AND RIP
[image: HITAID DLL]
This answer is related to `hittrace` feature of ollydbg
Attached is a `odbg110` plugin `hitaid.dll`
the dll has been `7zipped and hexedited` to be uploaded here as jpg
download hexedit and `delete first 10 bytes` and `save as hitaid.7z`
use 7zip to `extract hitaid.dll` from the archieve

ollydbg has a feature called `Hittrace` 
this plugin leverages that feature to achieve what is queried

put the dll in `odbg110 plugin path`
`open calc.exe` in odbg
`analyse` the main module viz calc.exe
`right click` in `disasm window` select `hittrace` in context menu
select `add all recognized procedures submenu`
all recognized procedures will be `marked with grey marker`
`run` the exe with `f9`
all instruction that were hit would be `colored red`
hitting `ctrl+L` from start of disasm window will cycle through all hits
use plugin to remove all the hits
if the required feature say `button 7 is clicked` now
the new code path that `pertains to button 7` would be colored red
new hits can be reached by selecting disasm window start and pressing ctrl+L
plugin can be used `repeatedly` to remove hits 
the app `need not be` paused for the interaction 
you can set f2 breakpoints as required in the new code path and reenable hittrace via disasm context menu

src below

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "plugin.h"
#pragma warning(disable:4100)
BOOL WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hi,DWORD reason,LPVOID reserved) 
{
    return 1;
};
extc int _export cdecl ODBG_Plugindata(char shortname[32]) 
{
    strcpy(shortname,"HitAid");
    return PLUGIN_VERSION;
};
extc int _export cdecl ODBG_Plugininit( int ollydbgversion,HWND hw,ulong *features) 
{
    Addtolist(0,0,"Hit Trace Aid Plugin by blabb"); 
    return 0;
};
extc int _export cdecl ODBG_Pluginmenu(int origin,char data[4096],void *item) 
{
    switch (origin)    
    {
    case PM_MAIN:
        strcpy(data,"0 &HitAid");
        return 1;
    default: break;
    };
    return 0;
};
extc void _export cdecl ODBG_Pluginaction(int origin,int action,void *item) 
{
    uchar *buff , *retu;
    unsigned long psize, i , addr;
    t_module * mod = Findmodule( Plugingetvalue(VAL_MAINBASE) );    
    addr = mod->codebase;
    if (origin==PM_MAIN)    
    {
        switch (action) 
        {
        case 0:
            retu = Findhittrace ( addr, &buff,&psize);
            for (i=0;i < psize;i++ )    {
                if ( retu[i] != ( TR_TRACE | TR_HIT )  ) 
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Modifyhittrace((addr+i) , (addr+i+1),ATR_REMOVE);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        };
    };
};
```

compiled with vs 2010 express and modified pdk by alex downloadable from www.ollydbg.de

```
cl /nologo /W4 /O1 /J /analyze /LD /WX /D"_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" hitaid.cpp    
/link /subsystem:windows /dll /ENTRY:DllEntryPoint/MERGE:.rdata=.text .\ollydbgvc7.lib
```